# Parse variable length datetime string which may not have zero padded units ("m/d/yyyy H:i:s" or "mm/dd/yyyy H:i:s")

Tags: php, string, datetime, date-conversion, date-parsing

How would you convert a date string that might be formatted like:

`m/d/yyyy H:i:s` or `mm/dd/yyyy H:i:s`

and format it like:

`yyyy-mm-dd H:i:s`

I can format either of the two inputs into my desired format, but not both.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`strtotime()` will have no problem parsing these two datetime formats.

Then just use its return unix timestamp integer with `date()` to generate the desired format string.

```
function format_date($date) {
    return date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($date));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way would be to simply transform it to unix time first with `strtotime` then run `strftime` on it afterwards... not the bes practice but it eliminates alot of the potential format parsing issues :-)

Answer (score 1):

How are you formatting it now?  If you're certain that those are the only two date formats you'll possibly have as input, then you can `explode()` it on the forward slashes, then if `strlen()` returns 1 on the month or the date, add a 0 as you're creating your `yyyy-mm-dd` string.

However, if you're not guaranteed that those are your only two input formats, then I would use `strtotime()` to convert it to epoch, then use `date()` to format it as you desire.  A slightly bigger processing hit, but much more universal code.